# Animate Navigation by scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I'd like to create a horizontal navigation which animates to a vertical navigation on scroll.

I've tried to do that with animate, but there I can only provide it like after 50 px scrolled animate in xxx seconds.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if (ScrolledFromTop > 50) {
    $('nav').animate({CSS CHANGES});
}
});
```

But I would like to do it like begin at 50px scrolled and the animation should be finished when I scrolled 100px. Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify more ?
I think you need a swipe like function but this time as a mouse event handler ?

Answer (score 0):

Whats the use case behind this ? Seems inpractical that a menu is stuck inbetween some transition when the user stops scrolling between 50 and 100 px.

Anyways you would need to map your current scrolled pixel value to the animation, like so:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset  >= 50 && window.pageYOffset  <= 100) {
      var percent = (window.pageYOffset - 50 ) * 2;
      animateMenu(percent);
  }else if(window.pageYOffset < 50) {
     animateMenu(0);
  }else if(window.pageYOffset > 100) {
      animateMenu(100);
  }
});

function animateMenu(percent){
   $('.menu').css({
      width: 100 - percent + "%",
      height: percent + "%"
   });
}
```

```css
.menu{
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.2s all ease-in;
  min-height: 50px;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```